# Matrix Determinant Calculation

Tags: matrices, determinant

I would like to solve the following question on matrix determinants.
$$
\begin{vmatrix} b+c&c+a&a+b\\b_1+c_1&c_1+a_1&a_1+b_1\\b_2+c_2&c_2+a_2&a_2+b_2\end{vmatrix} =X\begin{vmatrix} a&b&c\\a_1&b_1&c_1\\a_2&b_2&c_2\end{vmatrix} \;,\; X\in \mathbb{Z^+}
$$
Determine the value of $X$.

Can someone please give an idea  about the matrix manipulation required? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
a & b & c \\
a_1 & b_1 & c_1 \\
a_2 & b_2 & c_2 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0
\end{array}
\right) = \; \; \; ????
$$